# How does browser recognize that an input control is a server control so it should be sent to server?

Tags: asp.net, html

For example :
 if i define a plain HMLT control in aspx page and a server control marked as runt="server" then page is submited for postback in the formdata u can see the server controls id with value u have entered.

Answer (score 1):

The browser (client) takes all values in `input` elements defined with a `form` tag and sends them to the server when that form is submitted. Adding `runat="server"` does not affect the client directly (although it may alter the HTML generated by ASP.NET), it allows (among other things) that control to be handled more easily by ASP.NET. For example, when `runat="server"` is set you can set the control value, make it not visible, etc., from code (either in the page or in the codebehind).

See this MSDN article for more info (specifically the HTML Controls section):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973868.aspx

Comment: <input id="Location" type="text">
<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1">
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="Button" id="Button1">

U can see the above rendered html and when u see the below submitted form data there is a missing input (Location) controls data sent to server. 

__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUJMzY3MTcyMDIyZGQUNyhFP9fIhqreDHMyXVTQ5L878sZ3WfF JrCMKRZbeQ==
__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWBgLbrLviDwKM54rGBgLs0bLrBgKw45C8AQK84/y8AQL3jKLTDeKnD8GEDrn9unyF9wmZBVF/QVSeKAcE1Kv2QZSb1XYs
Button1:Button
TextBox1:

Comment: Try adding name="Location" to the first input element or set it to a value before submitting the form. Do you see a value then?

Comment: yes it does post in formdata. Does this mean that browser posts data only when the input element contains "name" attribute. If so why ?

Comment: @sas: because that's part of the HTML spec.  Name is a required attribute for form elements.

Comment: thnk you esbarro and chris  i did get the concept now

Comment: @sas cool, glad I could help. Since it seems like your question has been answered, you should accept whichever answer you feel is better by clicking the checkmark under the numbers on the left side. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

rsbarro is correct (i upvoted him), however his answer might be a bit confusing.

`runat="server"` does not affect the browser in any way.  It still sees input, selects, and the other standard HTML controls whether they were generated using .Net's controls or by putting the regular html tags in your markup.  The browser posts all form data into a "form" collection which is accessible server side using Request.Form["tagname"] or Request["tagname"]

Now in the asp.net, part of the page lifecycle inspects your markup for those runat="server" tags.  If it finds them then it will tell the control to load it's values from the Request.Form collection.  If an HTML control does not have runat="server", then it is not considered a server control and the only way to access the posted values is through Request.Form["tagname"].

There's more to it, so see rsbarro's link.

Hope this helps.